# Child component does not work in parent component after a connect with redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a parent component and a child component that is imported via import - Everything works fine.

As soon as i import the connect (react-redux) in the child component and export the export with **export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(myCHildComponent)** it is suddenly no longer marked as imported in the parent component and there is an undefined error.

Does anyone have any idea why that is?

Comment: Hello and welcome...Please take a look at how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please include the actual code - Components should be `PascalCase` and you don't need to pass in `null` to mapDispatchToProps, you can just omit that option entirely

Comment: How do you import your component ?